# knockout components binding attribute error

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-components

i want to add attribute id dynamically to tag but it is giving error

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "attr: function (){return {id:id} }"
>   Message: id is not defined"

My html-

```
<label data-bind="text:label"></label>
<span class="name" data-bind="attr:{id:id},html:value"></span>
<span class="cancelled" data-bind="html:cancel"></span>
<span class="currency-block" data-bind="html:amount"></span>
```

my view model-

```
this.listrows = [
            {layout:'basic', params:{icon:'icon-phone', items:[
            {item:'content', type:'basic', params:{id:'test', label:'From Account',value:'asuhdas'}}
            ]}},

            {layout:'basic', params:{icon:'icon-money', items:[
            {item:'content', type:'basic', params:{label: 'To Account:', value:''}}
            ]}}
]
```

I added attr:{id:id} still its giving error. can anyone help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing more of your HTML (therefore assuming your HTML is contained within a `foreach` which targets the `listrows.item` array), the `id` property is contained within your `params` object, so in order to reference it you'd need to specify `params.id`:

```
<span class="name" data-bind="attr: {id: params.id }, html: params.value"></span>
```

---

**Edit:** Based on comments:

> *above is my full html. I just want to add id to first span...*

In that case you need to access the viewmodel's value itself. You can't call just `id` as your viewmodel doesn't have its own `id` property. Instead you need to access it using:

```
attr: { id: listrows[0].items[0].params.id }
```

This assumes that you only want to access the `0th` index of both the `listrows` and `items` arrays.

Comment: I also believe this to be the issue, fully qualifying your bindings is always good practice.

Comment: @user3747168 could you please post more of your HTML?

Comment: I want to add id attribute to first span only.

Comment: above is my full html. I just want to add id to first span. And I already shared my view model code for that.

Comment: @james nt working. Is thr any other way to add attr id to span dynamically?

Comment: @user3747168 if it isn't working then the HTML you've included in your question *isn't* your full HTML. Please post the element(s) which contain the HTML you've posted.